# Problems with NIntegrate, errors NIntegrate::slwcon and NIntegrate::inumri

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I'm trying to integrate an interpolating function, but when I use `NIntegrate`, *Mathematica* gives me a series of error messages. I give you some examples:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand <<1>> has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{14.6836,14.6953},{-12.0000170249736609318194678966418287302531098248437047004699707031,-12.0133777475052196583721331180072411370929330587387084960937500000}}.
>
> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumri will be suppressed during this calculation.

I hope someone will help me to solve this problem.
Here is the code of a simplified version of my problem:

```
Ω = 
ImplicitRegion[
0 <= x <= 34 && -18 <= y <= 
0 && ! (12 < x < 15 && -12 < y || 15 < x < 20 && -3 < y || 
20 < x < 23 && -7 < y || 23 < x <= 34 && -3 < y), {x, y}];
RegionPlot[Ω, AspectRatio -> 0.5]

fi = NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∇\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(φ[x,
y]\)\) == NeumannValue[0, 
x == 0 && -18 < y < 0 || 0 < x < 34 && y == -18 || 
x == 34 && -18 < y < -3 || x == 23 && -7 < y < -3 || 
20 < x < 23 && y == -7 || x == 20 && -7 < y < -3 || 
15 < x < 20 && y == -3 || x == 15 && -12 < y < -3 || 
12 < x < 15 && y == -12 || x == 12 && -12 < y < 0], 
DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 1.5, 
0 <= x <= 12 && y == 0], 
DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 0.4, 
23 <= x <= 34 && y == -3]}, φ, {x, 
y} ∈ Ω]
φ[x_, y_] = φ[x, y] /. fi;

Integrale = 
NIntegrate[D[φ[x, y], x], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

Comment: This \\[CapitalOmega] =ImplicitRegion[..YourStuff..]; fi=\\[CurlyPhi][x,y] /. NDSolve[..YourStuff..][[1,1]]; Print[Plot3D[fi, {x,0,34}, {y,-18,0}]]; NIntegrate[D[fi,x], {x,y} \\[Element] \\[CapitalOmega]] fixes part of your problems with NIntegrate immediately failing, but still doesn't fix your convergence problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, on an `InterpolatingFunction` constructed by `NDSolve` one should use its `ElementMesh[..]` domain in `NIntegrate`, because that will invoke a special FEM integrator that is fast and accurate on the interpolating function.

One finds sometimes that the discretization of a region by `NDSolve` and by `NIntegrate` are not exactly the same, which can lead to sampling outside the domain. The problem can usually be fixed by using the `ElementMesh` created by `NDSolve`, but for some reason that did not work.  (The integral evaluates to `0.`, which does not agree with the graph of the integrand, which is negative.)
Further, sampling outside the domain seems still to occur and cause overflow and for `NIntegrate` to return unevaluated.

The next natural thing to try was to extend the function by zero outside the domain. One way this can be done with the option `"ExtrapolationHandler"`. This works.

Experimenting with a coding way to extend the function by zero if the input is not in the region tended to be unsuccessful.

```
Clear[φ];
fi = NDSolve[{
   Derivative[0, 2][φ][x, y] + Derivative[2, 0][φ][x, y] == NeumannValue[0, 
     x == 0 && -18 < y < 0 || 0 < x < 34 && y == -18 || 
      x == 34 && -18 < y < -3 || x == 23 && -7 < y < -3 || 
      20 < x < 23 && y == -7 || x == 20 && -7 < y < -3 || 
      15 < x < 20 && y == -3 || x == 15 && -12 < y < -3 || 
      12 < x < 15 && y == -12 || x == 12 && -12 < y < 0], 
   DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 1.5, 0 <= x <= 12 && y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 0.4, 23 <= x <= 34 && y == -3]},
   φ, {x, y} ∈ Ω,
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0 &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];

emesh = φ["ElementMesh"] /. First[fi];
NIntegrate[D[φ[x, y], x] /. First[fi], {x, y} ∈ emesh]
(*  -6.00409  *)
```

**Alternatives**

One needs to reevaluate the OP's `NDSolve` ***without*** the `"ExtrapolationHandler"` to test the following.

```
ClearAll[ff];
dxφ = Derivative[1, 0][φ] /. First[fi];
ff[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Check[dxφ[x, y], 0.];
NIntegrate[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh]
(*  -6.00409  *)
```

These, all of which use `emesh`, return zero (all return unevaluated as in the OP if `emesh` is replaced by `Ω`):

```
NIntegrate[D[φ[x, y], x] /. First[fi], {x, y} ∈ emesh]
NIntegrate[dxφ[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh]
NIntegrate[Check[dxφ[x, y], 0.], {x, y} ∈ emesh]
```

The following works but with limitations. `NIntegrate` will tell you that you cannot use `"GlobalAdaptive"` on regions, but the error message suggests that it is in fact used as a submethod.  But how to pass the submethod options? That's probably worth [it's own Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134910/real-and-imaginary-plots-of-a-complex-function?noredirect=1#comment364070_134910).

```
ClearAll[ff];
ff[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Quiet@Check[dxφ[x, y], 0.];
NIntegrate[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times....

```
    (*  -6.00189  *)
```

Comment: Very informative!

Answer (score 0):

It works by defining the ImplicitRegion in a different way:

```
\[CapitalOmega]1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 12 && -18 <= y <= 0, {x, y}];
\[CapitalOmega]2 = ImplicitRegion[12 <= x <= 15 && -18 <= y <= -12, {x, y}];
\[CapitalOmega]3 = ImplicitRegion[15 <= x <= 20 && -18 <= y <= -3, {x, y}];
\[CapitalOmega]4 = ImplicitRegion[20 <= x <= 23 && -18 <= y <= -7, {x, y}];
\[CapitalOmega]5 = ImplicitRegion[23 <= x <= 34 && -18 <= y <= -3, {x, y}];
\[CapitalOmega] = 
RegionUnion[\[CapitalOmega]1, \[CapitalOmega]2, \[CapitalOmega]3, \
\[CapitalOmega]4, \[CapitalOmega]5];
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Comment: What version are you using? [This does not fix it for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hw0i.png) (V11.0.0, Mac OSX).