# Can you use "MaxErrorIncreases" when numerically integrating over a region?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, finite-element-method

How do you pass the option `"MaxErrorIncreases"` to `NIntegrate[]` when integrating over a region?

Taking a simple ;) example from
[Problems with NIntegrate, errors NIntegrate::slwcon and NIntegrate::inumri](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134822/problems-with-nintegrate-errors-nintegrateslwcon-and-nintegrateinumri/134895#134895):

```
Ω = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x <= 34 && -18 <= y <= 0 && ! ((12 < x < 15 && -12 < y) ||
    (15 < x < 20 && -3 < y) || (20 < x < 23 && -7 < y) ||
    (23 < x <= 34 && -3 < y)), {x, y}];
fi = NDSolve[{
   Derivative[0, 2][φ][x, y] + Derivative[2, 0][φ][x, y] == NeumannValue[0, 
     x == 0 && -18 < y < 0 || 0 < x < 34 && y == -18 || 
      x == 34 && -18 < y < -3 || x == 23 && -7 < y < -3 || 
      20 < x < 23 && y == -7 || x == 20 && -7 < y < -3 || 
      15 < x < 20 && y == -3 || x == 15 && -12 < y < -3 || 
      12 < x < 15 && y == -12 || x == 12 && -12 < y < 0], 
   DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 1.5, 0 <= x <= 12 && y == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[φ[x, y] == 0.4, 23 <= x <= 34 && y == -3]},
   φ, {x, y} ∈ Ω,
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0 &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];
```

Then on this integral we get a warning that suggests raising `"MaxErrorIncreases"`:

```
ClearAll[ff];
dxφ = Derivative[1, 0][φ] /. First[fi];
ff[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Quiet@Check[dxφ[x, y], 0.];
NIntegrate[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times....Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration....

However, using the usual `Method` setting results in an error:

```
NIntegrate[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 5000}]
```

> NIntegrate::regm: Method GlobalAdaptive is not applicable for a region domain. Continuing with method Automatic.

Is it possible to use `"MaxErrorIncreases"` with `NIntegrate[]` over a region?

Comment: There is a method called `"FiniteElement"` that works for regions.  It is not the same as the automatic method chosen in this case.  (It gives a slightly different result and takes two to three times longer.)

Comment: Oddly enough, trying `NIntegrate[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, Method -> {Automatic, "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}]` throws an error saying only the sub-option `"SymbolicProcessing"` is supported. Hmm...

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon It is a feature. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the strategy, `"SymbolicDomainDecomposition"`:

```
NIntegrate[ff[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 Method -> {"SymbolicDomainDecomposition", 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 5000}}]
```

> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 5000 times....

```
(*  -6.0019  *)
```

It turns out not to be good way to integrate this function. Even with a setting of `"MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000`, the result still has a large error.
There are better methods for the example integral in the OP, which may be found in the [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134822/problems-with-nintegrate-errors-nintegrateslwcon-and-nintegrateinumri).